# Get full path from a process in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

there's something wrong with this api. i already check return function. no error. but output nothing.

```
HANDLE hSnapProcess = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
PROCESSENTRY32 process;
process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
Process32First(hSnapProcess, &process);
do
{
    if (process.th32ProcessID != 0)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProcess != NULL) 
        {
            wchar_t filePath[MAX_PATH];
            if (!GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH))
            {
                std::wcout << filePath << std::endl;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

} while (Process32Next(hSnapProcess, &process));
CloseHandle(hSnapProcess);
```

Comment: I'm confused. The code does exactly what it should: It doesn't output anything in case `GetModuleFileNameExW` succeeds, and dumps the contents of an uninitialized variable, if it fails. Why do you expect anything to be written to the console?

Comment: @IInspectable its just to check if it output to use later. by the way, what u means uninitialized variable?

Comment: @jab: No, it *is* uninitialized. This API does not make any guarantees about its out parameters on failure. If you are inclined to find out, call `GetModuleFileNameExW` passing `nullptr` as the process handle.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, you're OF COURSE right, I supposed wrongly that `filePath` was a `std::string`, but it obviously must be a `LPWSTR`. Deleting comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky how use LPWSTR as buffer? i think thats the wrong here.

Comment: What access rights does `GetModuleFileNameExW` need?

Comment: @ssbssa the process file path. only that.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch forget my comment with `LPWSTR`, `LPWSTR` is the same thing as `wchar_t*`. Using `wchar_t` as you did in your code is fine. Tthe code as it stands in your question works fine, provided you _remove_ the `!` in front of `GetModuleFileNameExW`.

Comment: *To retrieve the name of the main executable module for a remote process, use the `GetProcessImageFileName` or `QueryFullProcessImageName` function. This is more efficient and more reliable than calling the `GetModuleFileNameEx` function with a NULL module handle.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with this API, the only thing that's wrong here is your code.

The documentation clearly states that the return value of [`GetModuleFileNameExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw) is the length of the string copied to the buffer.

If the return value is 0, the function has failed.

So you simply need to write this:

```
...
if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH) != 0)
{
   // handle "success" case
}
...
```

BTW `CloseHandle(hProcess);` should be inside the `if (hProcess != NULL)` block.

**Full working example with error checks**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main()
{
  HANDLE hSnapProcess = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

  if (hSnapProcess != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnapProcess, &process);
    do
    {
      if (process.th32ProcessID != 0)
      {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, process.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProcess != NULL)
        {
          wchar_t filePath[MAX_PATH];
          if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH))
          {
            std::wcout << filePath << std::endl;
          }
          else
          {
            std::wcout << L"GetModuleFileNameExW failed with error" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
          }

          CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
      }

    } while (Process32Next(hSnapProcess, &process));

    CloseHandle(hSnapProcess);
  }
  else
  {
    std::wcout << L"CreateToolhelp32Snapshot failed with error" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: as documentation say if failure it will return 0. thats why i just put **!** in front. but the case is not that. the **filePath** not output full path a process.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. `GetModuleFileNameExW` returns 0 in case of error that's why you should have `if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH))` (without `!`) or `if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH) != 0)`

Comment: @Dwersonbusch By putting `!` in front you made `if` branch work when return value is `0`,  that is when `GetModuleFileNameExW ` failed...

Comment: Ok, i understand now. but it not output. whats wrong here?

Comment: @Dwersonbusch on success `GetModuleFileNameExW` returns a non null value. Your original code executes `std::wcout << filePath << std::endl;` only in case of error, which actually doesn't occur here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i already change my code to use **!= 0** still no output nothing

Comment: @Dwersonbusch The code in the question is what matters, not what you see on your screen. We aren't a debugging service.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch the code as it stands in your question works fine, provided you _remove_ the `!` in front of `GetModuleFileNameExW`.

Comment: Probably what happened is that the asker has been changing stuff at random and posted the version with the bogus boolean check. When the code is fixed it fails to get the module file name because the process is protected in some way.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch I edited my answer and put a full working example with error checks.

Comment: ok, the error return 5 as i check in msdn it means access denied. and change the first parameter OpenProcess. it works.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch instead of saying "thank you", you should accept and/or upvote the question.

Comment: You accepted this answer which passes the wrong access rights to `OpenProcess` ......

Comment: seriously i  want to accept your answer. cause you enthusiast to respons my question. whereas struggle together. can u edit your answer to OpenProcess paremeter 1. so it may helpfull for other maybe.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch these are the rules: accept/ and/or upvote the answer that you think is the most useful to you. Upvote the other answers that you think are still useful.

Comment: @Dwersonbusch I didn't understand your comment. But anyway nobody said your question was a "non sense question".

Answer (score 3):

Two clear mistakes can be seen in your code, both can be understood by reading the documentation.

Firstly, in [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw):

> The handle must have the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION and PROCESS_VM_READ access rights.

Your handle only has `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`.

Secondly, again in [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw):

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies the length of the string copied to the buffer.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero.

Your logic is back-to-front. Replace:

```
if (!GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH))
```

with

```
if (GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH))
```

Comment: Using only `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` works here on my platform (Windows 10). (I still upvoted your answer anyway).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure, but I'm still wondering why it works on my platform with only `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`

Comment: @Jabberwocky, at some point the Windows team changed the case where `hModule` is `NULL` to work the same as  `QueryFullProcessImageName`, which is based on an `NtQueryInformationProcess` system call that requires only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access, so you can query the names of high integrity and protected processes. This is an undocumented implementation detail. Use `QueryFullProcessImageName` instead. The old implementation, which is still used to query DLLs, requires reading the PEB, which requires the right to query all information and read the memory of the process.